# Visual Studio 2017 Code Output Not Showing

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community and I've faced the problem of the output of my code not displaying.

Before, when I run C code (usually with Ctrl+F5), the output would be displayed on the output window, but for some reason now when I do it there is no output (a command prompt-like window literally blinks and disappears).

I haven't changed anything and I'm really confused as to why this error is occurring. Does anybody have any ideas why?

Here's the screen after writing a simple "Hello World" program and pressing Ctrl+F5.

[image]

My code output would normally appear in the console box on the bottom, but now it just shows the build results.

When I create a new project, I click on Empty Project, then add an item and save it as a .c source code. I've been using the same method but have suddenly encountered a problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't read any of that.  vtc as 'Unclear'.

Comment: Does it run and display something with the debugger?

Comment: After debugging it, it says on the console multiple times that it "cannot find PDB file."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience everybody, but I've found the issue. Apparently Visual Studio 2017 has some new modifications from previous versions that I have been using.

Anybody who faces the same issue as I have may refer to the following video link that I used:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Slgwyta-JkA

Answer (score 2):

For Windows only:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

put `system("Pause")` right at the end.

for cross-platform stuff use

```
getchar();
```

instead of `system("Pause");`

Comment: He doesn't need system("Pause"); because when compiling with Ctrl+F5 VS automatically adds it

Comment: just tested and VS 2017 did not add it for me.