# Where should I be looking for the output in visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017, output

So I am not a programmer but I've decide to learn C and have found a website with great material (https://www.learn-c.org/).  As a student I was able to get Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 for free.  So as you may understand I'm not well versed in either C, programming, or VS2017. For lesson 1 on this site I must create my own Hello_World program.  In VS2017 I opened an empty project and then opened a new file (Test.c).  I believe my code is correct, however when I try to run it (Shift + F5) I do not see the "Hello World".  A command prompt flickers on my screen for a bit.  In a panel labeled "Output" on the bottom of VS 2017 I get this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Test.c
1>Project1.vcxproj -> C:\Users\Fabien\source\repos\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So my question is where should I be seeing "Hello, World!" ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
printf("Hello World");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program is working exactly the way you wrote it to work. It prints the line of output and then immediately exits by returning from main(). If you want it to pause so you can read the output, you'll need to do so.

Comment: warning: Visual studio has never been a C compiler according to the standard C. I advice you to learn with a conforming compiler as clang.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 Code Output Not Showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649562/visual-studio-2017-code-output-not-showing)

Answer (score 2):

You program is working correctly but it is executed in a separate window and it is closed immediately after it finishes so you don't get a chance to see the output. You can use a  function that halts the program and waits for input, for example `getchar` like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello World");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

this way the program will wait for input and then close.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift-F5</kbd>, unless you've reconfigured the default keys, is to *stop* debugging, so I'm not sure why you think that would help :-)

Pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> on it's *own* will run your code, but in a mode that means it will simply exit once done, and the output window will disappear. If you *need* to do it that way, you can simply put a `getchar()` before exiting.

However, I'm not a big fan of having to change code just for debugging and, in any case, exiting may occur somewhere *other* than the end of `main()`.

So I find it preferable to simply use <kbd>Ctrl-F5</kbd> to run it in such a way that the IDE itself will leave the window open until you press a key:

```
<Your program output goes here>
Press any key to continue . . .
```